# How can I separate this NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

Since I can't get the logic to separate parsed string

> tooltipHtml:" (26.3 km / 29 mins)"

and I want to remove other part except '**26.3 km**' & '**29 mins**'. Sometimes instead of '**mins**' there can be '**hrs- mins**'

Comment: Do you want the part between the parentheses?

Comment: yes. only the part between ()

Comment: I'd probably split on the `(`, the `/`, and the `)`, and ignore the rest, assuming that the format is reasonably well fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NSString componentsSeparatedByString: method to separate them along the "(" , "/" and ")"

```
NSArray *components = [myString componentsSeparatedByString: @"("];
NSArray *componentsTwo = [[components objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
NSString *firstString = [componentsTwo objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *componentsThree = [componentsTwo objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString: @")"];
NSString *secondString = [componentsThree objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or you could use Regex method, however I'm not really familiar with them, so I can't tell you how exactly to do it, you'll have to look around a bit.

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution. It is better to get the range of the "(" and ")" and simply get the substring between those ranges.

Comment: True, but if something's different (ex: T instead of t, it doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use RegEx instead you could do:

```
NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(?<=[(])[^)]*" options:nil error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regEx matchesInString:str options:Nil range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *r in matches) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [str substringWithRange:r.range]);
}
```

Output: 26.3 km / 29 mins

Or if you prefer to have them separated further use:

```
NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(?<=[(|/])[^)|/]*" options:nil error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regEx matchesInString:str options:Nil range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *r in matches) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [str substringWithRange:r.range]);
}
```

Output: 
26.3 km
29 mins

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *newString =[@"tooltipHtml:\" (26.3 km / 29 mins)\"" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@\"tooltipHtml:\""
                                 withString:@""];



    newString =[newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"("
                                 withString:@""];
```

And so forth...

(I might have some syntax typos but you get the point, use the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method)

Comment: What does that accomplish beyond making it harder to parse out the rest?

Comment: I think that at the point he's left it the string starts with `26.3 km`. So you could take the `floatValue` and have the first number.

Comment: @HotLicks what do you mean? The question states he wants to remove 'tooltipHtml:"' not parse out the numbers

Comment: @HotLicks actually I don't know what he wants. Poorly written question

Comment: The above code will not remove "tooltipHtml:", even if that *was* what he wanted.